# Check if the number is Armstrong Number c++

Tags: c++

*I wrote this code for checking whether the number is Armstrong or not*

**CODE** -

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int sum=0;
int originaln=n;
while(n!=0){
    int lastdigit= n%10;
    sum+= pow(lastdigit,3);
    n=n/10;
}

if(sum==originaln){
    cout<<"Armstrong Number"<<endl;
}    
else{
    cout<<"Not Armstrong"<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

While giving input as 153, it is giving an output - "Not Armstrong".
And giving 371 as input, it is giving an output - "Armstrong Number".

*BOTH 153 AND 371 ARE ARMSTRONG NUMBERS*

Please someone help me with this code.

Comment: Your code outputs actually nothing, since it [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02fc965ecda84ca4).

Comment: Have you tried debugging this program via a debugger/ just printing logs in your code?

Comment: Are you expecting only three digits numbers as input? I'm asking because you raise to third power, while in general it should be the number of digits: https://oeis.org/A005188

Comment: Your code actually [works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/3PnvhWhsb) for 153, of course besides the caveat in the current answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) is for calculating floating-point numbers and its result may contain errors. Avoid using that for calculation on integers.

In other words, you should do

```
sum += lastdigit * lastdigit * lastdigit;
```

instead of

```
sum+= pow(lastdigit,3);
```